# Debian Python 2.5 including module from AlchemyAPI

Tags: python, installation, alchemyapi

Trying to install **AlchemyAPI.py-2.5**

Can't get example running.

Debian 6.0

#### python example/sentiment.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example/sentiment.py", line 4, in <module>
    import AlchemyAPI
ImportError: No module named AlchemyAPI
```

How do I install that module?
in README it says:

> To install this module, copy the desired AlchemyAPI.py file into your desired
> Python import directory.

What is my desired directory if I'm running on debian ?

Very confusing, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename `AlchemyAPI.py-2.5` to `AlchemyAPI.py` for it to be importable, and add it to the PYTHONPATH (which includes the Python package directories and the working dir).

In your example you can copy the file to: `example/AlchemyAPI.py`.

Comment: You welcome.  
Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.